# Isolating ports on a router

Tags: vlan

A discussion with the manufacturer stated this configured is not supported or even possible with the router's hardware and OS.

Comment: Still same advice: Look at the complete switch hw config (googling the robocfg source shows the command is `robocfg show`, hopefully...), see if anything looks odd. Don't try to do everything at once, do simple pieces, and *test them*. Start with the 3 `robocfg` statements, and `eth1.[12]`. See if the packets show up correctly (`tcpdump`), or if that already causes the ports to become unresponsive. If you are unlucky, port `8t` is connected internally to somewhere that only understands VLAN tag 1. *Test* this hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, of course port 8 refers to the CPU (or rather SoC), and of course it expects tagged frames. The point is that I know router SoC's that only work with a particular VLAN tag on that port (for whatever reason). Also, please edit question with output of `robocfg show`, or whatever the correct command is, to show the complete configuration of the switch hw before you change anything. Does `robocfg vlan 1 ports "0 1 4 5t 7 8t` work on its own? Does `robocfg` allow multiple setups on the same line, or some sort of setup/commit (in case you confuse the hardware by setting it up in steps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpretation of the default setup so far:

The Realtek switch already tags frames with `VLAN 1`, the other LAN ports are tagged by the Broadcom switch and show up *tagged* on port 8, which is connected to the SoC. The WAN port shows up *untagged* on port 8 (if that's what the "u" means, the `robocfg` source is unhelpful here, and I couldn't find a datasheet).

Guess: The SoC ethernet driver associates *untagged* frames with `eth0`, and frames tagged with `VLAN 1` with `eth1`, and drops frames with all other VLAN tags. Which means you can configure the Broadcom switch all you want, you won't be able to isolate any ports using VLAN tags.

That behaviour is testable by removing `eth0` and `eth1` from all bridges, playing around with the VLAN ids for `... 8t` and `... 8u` a bit, and send in packets without and with different ids from both sides.

So the task is to find out what the SoC ethernet driver actually does, and if it's configurable in any way. If you could tell it, say, to route VLAN id 10 to `eth2` and VLAN id 20 to `eth3`, you'd be all set.

If it's not the SoC ethernet driver, but, say, `eth1` is already a VLAN slave of `eth0` and the kernel does the redirection, then so much the better.

Look in `dmesg` after boot for any hints for `eth0` and `eth1`, find out where `/sys/class/net/eth[01]/device` points to and which kernel module is responsible, etc. That needs a bit of sleuthing and looking at various things.

**Edit**

1) The [Realtek RTL8365MB](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=15&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=296) switch has its own kernel module `rtl8365mb`. [Source](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/tree/master/release/src-rt-6.x.4708/linux/linux-2.6.36/drivers/char/rtl8365mb) (possibly different variant) is available. [Datasheet](http://realtek.info/pdf/rtl8366_8369_datasheet_1-1.pdf) of a very similar chip is available. With all this info, it should be possible to write something similar to `robocfg`/`swconfig` and control the switch. Apparently some [thought about that](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/vlans-on-ac88u-lan5-8.30664/), but I couldn't google any successes.

2) According to the `robocfg` source, the VLAN table implementation of the Broadcom and of the Realtek chip seem to be similar enough to conclude from 8.12.6 in the datasheet that `t` means "add tag for egress" and `u` means "remove tag unconditionally for egress".

3) Your SoC chipset seems to be a BCM47XX with three on-chip etherports, two of which seem to be to used somewhere else, and on is `eth0`:

```
fwd0: Broadcom BCM47XX 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet Controller 7.14.131.56 (r641653)
fwd1: Broadcom BCM47XX 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet Controller 7.14.131.56 (r641653)
eth0: Broadcom BCM47XX 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet Controller 7.14.131.56 (r641653)
```

The controlling module is `et`, the [source](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/blob/master/release/src-rt/et/sys/et_linux.c) (possibly a different variant) is available.

It's not entirely clear to me if `eth1` and `eth2` also belong to this driver, and are just registered later, or if they belong to `bcmdhd` (WLAN), and/or if they are renamed by udev at some stage:

```
Dongle Host Driver, version 1.363.45.58013 (r651509)
Compiled in drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd on Jun 21 2017 at 10:36:36
Register interface [eth1]  MAC: 34:97:f6:20:1b:a8
... 
Dongle Host Driver, version 1.363.45.58013 (r651509)
Compiled in drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd on Jun 21 2017 at 10:36:36
Register interface [eth2]  MAC: 34:97:f6:20:1b:ac
```

So the next step is to sort out all the network interfaces. Please edit question with output of `ip -d link`, and also `ls -l /sys/class/net/*/lower*` and `ls -l /sys/class/net*`. If that doesn't provide sufficient information, `udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth0` and `udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth1` would also be interesting, assuming the router uses `udev`.

Another thing to look for is where the configuration information sits, so `modinfo rtl8365mb`, `modinfo et` may produce something interesting, as well as `find /etc | xargs grep eth` or similar things.

As you can see, I am fishing for information; this is slow and not easy to do remotely without the system in front of me. Feel free to do these or additional steps in any ways that sorts things out. The goal is to find the place that says "`eth1` is somehow associated to `eth0` with VLAN tag 1".

Comment: So it's not PCI based, and the kernel module does its own thing. Please put `dmesg` after boot into a pastebin or similar, and edit question with link. And while you're at it, add the output of `lsmod`.